# sudden appearance of $ sign in .exe files

Tags: windows, hard-drive, virus, malware

I have a couple of software in my external hard drive. All after a sudden (maybe by means of a virus or something), all my .exe file names got a "$" at the end. I mean a file named "setup.exe" is now "setup$.exe". The files are not temporary and I had had the same files before. Moreover, these exe files has gone hidden and a file with the correct name ("setup.exe") with a yellow-disk icon appears in the same directory. Regardless of the size of the original exe file, the now yellow one has the same size for all (around 6-7 MB I guess).

No need to say that these yellowish ones don't open or execute while the original ones (with that specious sign) work just fine. The more interesting issue is all my exe files on my PC's internal hard are totally OK! So if there is any virus, it must be stuck in my external hard drive (funny or not?).

I also did scan my whole PC and hard drive a couple of times and no virus was found (by ESET Smart Security 9).

Does anyone have any idea about what these yellowish files are and how to get rid of them?

Comment: [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](//superuser.com/q/100360)

Comment: This seems to be a really exhaustive post. I will look at it at a good time.

Answer (score 0):

Things are changing in mysterious ways without you asking them to.  What you're describing is absolutely not normal/good.  Make sure you've backed up any data that is important to you (because data loss, soon, seems entirely probable).

Then get this malware off of your computer.  If ESET detects nothing, try some other software that does detect something.  Repeat as needed.  (In other words, try multiple pieces of cleaning software.)  If you have to re-install the operating system, then do that (whether you do that, or have a professional do that).  Or just get a new computer if you prefer.  (Seriously, with tablets being so cheap, that may often be a preferable option, rather than bringing an older system into a repair shop.)

Until that is done, expect greater chances of data theft (often done invisibly; you don't have a real way to know if that's already been done or not), more data destruction, and/or other problems (like data being changed).

If this answer seems like bad/unpleasant news, I'm sorry.  But I speak the truth.  You suspect malware ("malicious software"... you did mention the idea of "a virus") and I confirm that's the cause that makes sense for what you describe.  To protect yourself from additional problems starting to occur, this must be dealt with.

If you want to try cleaning this yourself, some freebee software that a lot of people like to use (for cleaning) include:

- SuperAntiSpyware (yes, I know the name might sound cheesy, but frequently it works pretty good for people)
- MalwareBytes
- Maybe CCleaner

and many other anti-virus software have free/trial versions.  Microsoft's Security Essentials, AVG Free, Avast, are just some that come to mind.  Some Internet providers, like my local phone company, also partner with some commercial software, so you could ask about that too.